# File not uploading to dynamic directory in Yii

Tags: file-upload, yii

For a file upload I have the action below.  This creates a dir with the currentDate as I have defined in my model and a uploads my file renaming it to the ImageId.

The problem is that the directory and Image are both created within the same dir.  I need the Image to be placed in the newly created directory though.  Any ideas?

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['ImageUpload'];
$model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
if($model->save())
{
    exec("mkdir -p " . Yii::app()->basePath . "/../images/uploads/$data->currentDate");
    $model->image->saveAs(Yii::app()->getBasePath()."/../images/uploads/$data->currentDate/$model->ImageId");
    $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->ImageId));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have anything in $model->ImageId?

I'm using roughly the same code:

```
if (!file_exists ($fileSavePath))
    mkdir ($fileSavePath, 0, true);

$fileSavePath .= $form->my_file->name;
$form->my_file->saveAs ($fileSavePath);
```

Comment: @Irobb, $model->ImageId is populated during the execution of the form.  Like I said a file uploaded and renamed to $model->ImageId.  The directory is also made just the image is not put in that folder.  I tried incorporating your code but was unsuccessful.  Can you see how to incorporate what I have into what you have.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just to be sure, do an echo to see what the path is: 

    echo (Yii::app()->getBasePath() .
  "/../images/uploads/$data->currentDate/$model->ImageId");